# Connecting to a device on the local network over TCP *sometimes* fails with "No Route To Host" socket error

Tags: c#, android, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm making an Android app (using Unity and C#) which needs to connect over TCP to a different app running on another device (using the .NET `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` and `TcpListener` classes). The way this works is the host app broadcasts a UDP packet giving info on its local IP (192.168.x.x) and its TCP listening port. Upon receiving the UDP packet, the Android app attempts to connect to the TCP endpoint given. Most of the time (~80%), this works perfectly and the two devices establish a valid TCP connection. Sometimes though, the Android app receives the UDP packet, tries to connect over TCP but a "No Route To Host" socket error shows up instead; even trying again upon receiving the next UDP packet fails.

I'm suspecting that this is to do with the router creating different subnets. I'm not very familiar with networking code, so I'm not sure how to forward the TCP request over to a different subnet of the local network. What's weird is that the UDP packet is always received no matter what; and most of the time, the TCP request will fail for 10 minutes straight then start working again like nothing happened.

```cs
public async Task<bool> ConnectToHost(IPEndPoint endpoint) {
    try {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.NoDelay = true;
        IPAddress ipv4 = endpoint.Address;
        Debug.Log("IPv4: " + ipv4);
        await client.ConnectAsync(ipv4, endpoint.Port);   // <--- this call throws the SocketException
        Debug.Log("Connected.");

        // ...

        return true;
    }catch(SocketException se) {
        Debug.LogError("[TCPClient] Socket Exception (" + se.ErrorCode + "), cannot connect to host: " + se.ToString(), this);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        Debug.LogError("[TCPClient] Error, cannot connect to host: " + e.ToString(), this);
    }
    return false;//Could not connect
}
```

The `ConnectAsync()` call fails on the client side, giving the following SocketException (error code 10065, `WSAEHOSTUNREACH`); on server side, no trace of the message is ever seen.

```java
05-29 13:31:54.591: I/Unity(24587): IPv4: 192.168.1.21
05-29 13:31:54.591: I/Unity(24587):  
05-29 13:31:54.591: I/Unity(24587): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 48)
05-29 13:31:58.103: E/Unity(24587): [TCPClient] Socket Exception (10065), cannot connect to host: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No route to host
05-29 13:31:58.103: E/Unity(24587):   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult.CheckIfThrowDelayedException () [0x00014] in <9eab73f5583e4ab3921ff80e74ccdb29>:0 
05-29 13:31:58.103: E/Unity(24587):   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0002c] in <9eab73f5583e4ab3921ff80e74ccdb29>:0 
05-29 13:31:58.103: E/Unity(24587):   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.EndConnect (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <9eab73f5583e4ab3921ff80e74ccdb29>:0 
05-29 13:31:58.103: E/Unity(24587):   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00019] in <a6266edc72ee4a578659208aefcdd5e1>:0
```

Comment: It's probably not your code; it's probably a network issue, but not anything subnet-related. I am assuming you have a typical setup, with 2 WiFi devices connecting to the same router, and that router has assigned each device its address via DHCP. Maybe put a Wireshark box on the network and see if you can see the ARP requests (from the client) for 192.168.1.21.